# Typescript can't see this type with vue.js

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, webpack, vue.js

I have this code:

```
const c = Vue.extend({
    data() {
        return {
            msg: 'Hello'
        }
    },
    methods: {
        greet(): string {
            this.msg = "asdasd"; // Type '"asdasd"' is not assignable to type 'Function'.
            return this.msg + ' world';
        }
    }
});
```

But `this.msg = "asdasd"` shows an error: `Type '"asdasd"' is not assignable to type 'Function'.`. This happens in both VS and during webpack build. It feels like typescript cannot see this type properly, even though I use `Vue.extend` What could be the reasons of this?

My `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./built/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es5",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
  },
  "include": [
    "./ViewModels/**/*"
  ]
}
```

I have also removed all the mentioning of typescript from `.csproj` file, because VS could not build typescript (and I do not want it as I use webpack to build it anyway)

Webpack config: https://gist.github.com/archeg/743348021c59563a9d479993bc0c349f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are struggling with the same issue: I switched to `https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component` and it started to work properly.

For example the code I posted, will look like this with `vue-class-component`:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Component from 'vue-class-component';

@Component({})
class Example extends Vue {
    msg = "Hello";
    greet(): void {
      this.msg = "asdasd"; //This is a proper here.
      return this.msg + ' world';
    }
}
```